# Issue in setting imageView Width

Tags: android, imageview, image-scaling

I want to set image view's width according to screen size and height as static 200dp.

> The rectangular image in the background is actual image size.

[image]

> If I use custom ImageView, it looks like this[image]
>
> What should be done to just manage the width of image without
>   strecthing?
>
> This is the imageView In xml

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userBlurrIv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

> I am using glide :

```
 Glide.with(activity!!)
            .load(File(path))
            .apply(bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(22)))
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .into(userBlurrIv)
```

Comment: Show some code for more clarification

Comment: Please check @Rafasanjani

Comment: try this `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: it cuts the image from top

Comment: you don't want to scale your imageview, and also want keep your image fully display, so only one solution, design your image size fit with your view lol

Comment: try adding imageview as a child view to relative layout or linear layout...& set width to matchparent.

Comment: I am using constraint layouts